# Audio Beat Detection in C#

Tags: c#

Using System.IO BinaryReader object found in .NET mscorlib assembly, I ran a loop that dumped each byte value from a .wav file into Excel spreadsheet. For simplicity sake, I recorded a two second 4K signal from signal generator into software sequencer and saved as monaural wave file. The software I sequence music with shows a resolution of 1ms - which is 44.11 samples(assuming 44.1K sample rate). What I find curious is that the data extracted via ReadInt16() method(starting at position 44 in .wav file) shows varied numbers with integers switching signs seemingly at random- whereas the visual sine wave within sequencer is completely uniform with respect to amplitude and frequency. With 16 bit resolution, I determined that for each sample first byte was frequency resolution and the second amplitude, is correct?

Question: How can I intelligently interpret the integers pulled from wave file for the ultimate purpose of determining rhythmic beats?

Many thanks...........Mickey

Comment: Thank you Heandel I will review the document. To answer your question, yes I simply invoked ReadInt16 method to pull out an decimal integer values.

Answer (score 3):

For a WAV file with 16 bits per sample, it is *not* the case that the first byte of the sample is frequency resolution and the second byte is amplitude.  Both bytes together indicate the sample's amplitude at that specific point in time.  The two bytes are interpreted as a 2-byte integer, so the values will range from -32768 to +32767.

I do not know how your sequencer works or what it is displaying.  From your description, it sounds as if your sequencer is using FFT to convert the audio from time-domain (which is what a WAV file is) to frequency-domain (which is a graph with frequency along the x-axis and frequency amplitude along the y-axis).  A WAV file does not contain frequency information.

Comment: Ok I see. From the 2 byte output groupings, the first byte value is usually much higher than 2 byte value, hence I drew the erroneous conclusion that it was a frequency/amplitude designation. So is there some kind of legend or mapping document that explains the logic. If binary reader output data can range from -32768 to 32767 for position 1, i.e. byte 1, then what is the purpose of byte 2?

Comment: @Mickey: no, 2 bytes per sample means that the value of each sample (there are 44,100 samples per second) is stored as a two-byte integer (aka `Int16`). The range of possible values for `Int16` is -32768 to +32767. You seem to be thinking that each of the two bytes in the sample is storing a different quantity, and they're not. The two bytes are fundamentally bound together as a single `Int16`.

Comment: So I have created a 1 second mono .wav file, for which the audio data chunk comprises 88200 bytes. As I scroll down this 88200 output list, I see integer values like...29570,750,-29658,1305... in this type of high/low sequence. If each of the 88200 positions is 1 byte of data, then it takes two positions to make up the sample resolution. Or am I missing something here? If so, then what is the significance of 2nd byte in every instance of this dual sequence?

Comment: A 1 second mono WAV file means you have 44,100 samples. Each sample uses 2 bytes to store its value, which means each sample value can be anywhere between -32768 and +32767. You have 88200 bytes of data because you have 44100 samples, each of which uses two bytes to store its value (as a 2-byte integer). It's best if you stop thinking about your audio data as a series of bytes, and instead think of it as a series of `Int16` values.

Comment: Very well. So if there are 44100 samples that can range in resolution from -32768 to +32767, then why are there 88200 data points? To me it seems like too much data returned. That's why I thought the 2nd number in the sequence was some kind of delimeter.

Comment: @Mickey: there *aren't* 88200 data points. There are 44100 data points (aka "samples"), each of which uses 2 bytes to store the sample value. This results in 88200 *bytes*.

Comment: So if I sum the signed integers in bytes 1 and 2, this would yield the correct resolution for sample 1, sum 3 and 4 = sample 2 etc?

Comment: You don't add them.  It's one number that is 16 bits (2 bytes) long.  If I wrote "6458" that's six-thousand four-hundred fifty-eight, not one-hundred twenty-two!  (64+58), right?

Comment: The negative numbers are just erroneous interpretations of only part of each two-byte number.  Kind of like thinking that the "23" is odd in the even "2392" just because you're only looking at half of it.